# How can I have point on today when running org-agenda?

Tags: org-agenda

This is a general problem I'm struggling with, but I have to begin somewhere.

This problem didn't happen before.

When I run org-agenda, point ends up on the bottom of the entries, instead of todays' date.

I also see this if I run some org-agenda-custom-command and I get a big list and point is on the last entry, when I really want it on the first entry;)

Comment: Before what? What did you do to change it? (FWIW, it does not happen here:  today rules.) At the very least, provide versions of Emacs and Org mode. I would suspect something in your config, so I would suggest that you set up a new config with just your `org-agenda-files` set up (no other customizations at all). Does `C-c a a` still end up at the end? Then add `org-agenda-custom-commands` and test the other case. And report back! With details!